# Unable to run test case in angular2 due to 'router-outlet'

Tags: angular, routes, karma-jasmine

I am running my test case using "ng test". It fails at routing level. Please find the screenshot.

[image]

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

is in `app.component.html`

How to add the router test in app.component.spec.ts to pass test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the below steps issue fixed

1) create router-stubs.ts in testing folder in root folder with below code

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick()'
  }
})
export class RouterLinkStubDirective {
  @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any;
  navigatedTo: any = null;

  onClick() {
    this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams;
  }
}
```

2) add below code to your app.component.spec.ts

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLinkStubDirective } from '../testing/router-stubs'; 

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent, RouterLinkStubDirective ],
      schemas:      [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      let comp    = fixture.componentInstance;
      // trigger initial data binding
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });   
  });
```

It fixed the error "router-outlet not a known element"

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, you don't need to create your own router stub for this.
All you have to do is import the angular test router module instead of the real one or none at all.

In your TestBed.configureTestingModule

```
  imports: [RouterTestingModule]
```